# Bug in tabbing order of Share Feedback modal

Tags: bug, review, user-interface, accessibility, keyboard

I've discovered a bug in the tabbing order when the Share Feedback modal is shown from the Review Queue.

1. Select "Share feedback"
2. Click "Submit" to open the modal
3. Ensure that "Custom comment" or "Question is too broad" is selected
4. Repeated press <kbd>Shft</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate around the DOM elements within the modal.  After leaving focus of the selected radio button, the focus jumps out of the modal and onto the "Add a comment" text/link in the parent layer.

Navigating the modal using only <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not trigger this bug -- the focus remains solely on elements within the modal.

[image: screenshot of first answers feedback modal]

Answer (score 4):

I think there's one more bug. Following the same steps in the question for the *First Answers* review queue, if you're using <kbd>Tab</kbd> it'll cycle through *Answer is unclear* and the Help Center links but never focuses on *Answer needs supporting information*.

Doing the same in the *First Questions* review queue will jump over some of the feedback options, but does focus on the *Question is unclear* option.

This seems overall inconsistent because after having chosen *Custom comment* -- it will allow you to choose one alternative option within the modal, but not the others.

Comment: Tricky to reproduce.  In the First Answers modal, if you Tab through the modal BEFORE a radio button is selected -- everything is fine.  After a radio button is selected, I can reproduce your findings.